# Inserting elements in the array from input [Core Dump (Segmentation fault)]

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, memory

I wrote an algorithm that sorts elements in an array. Now I'm trying to solve it by taking elements from input but the compiler gives me this error -> "Core Dump (Segmentation fault)"

```
int array[100];
int num;

printf("How many elements do you want to insert? --> ");
scanf("%d", num);

for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    printf("Insert the element --> ");
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    for (int j=i+1; j<num; j++){
        if (array[i] > array[j]){
            int tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: You need to check if the input is greater than `100` and make it `100` if it is.

Comment: I have this error after I insert the number of elements that I want to add in to the array

Comment: See my answer. `scanf` requires pointers to the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right here:

```
scanf("%d", num);
```

You need to pass a pointer to an `int`. This should be:

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```